# Windows update error 0x80244022

Tags: windows, windows-update

I get this:

There were some problems installing updates, but we'll try again later. If you keep seeing this and want to search the web or contact support for information, this may help: (0x80244022)

Windows says: *Some settings are managed by your organization

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Override the group policy of your intranet by setting this registry key to 0 in regedit.exe

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\WindowsUpdate\AU\UseWUServer`

Then restart windows update service (wuauserv).

If you want to create a .reg file:

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\WindowsUpdate\AU]
"UseWUServer"=dword:00000000
```

Of course if possible, it's better to ask your admin to fix the WUS server to get updates normally.

Comment: OMG Thank you.  I know this is an old question but it finally got me to the answer.

Comment: thank you, yes clearly off topic but perhaps not so much as relevant to devs on windows. As I still need to use this I clarified the answer.

Comment: hmmm don't have `WindowsUpdate` in `Windows` in my registry in Windows 10.